# how do i return sum from array_to_string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i am in the need of sum result from array_to_string function which has only integer value in array.

```
SELECT
    state_name,
    "ST_CODE" ,
    dist_name ,
    "DIST_CODE",
    subdist_name,
    "SUBDIST_CODE",
    array_to_string(array_agg(distinct jan_sale::numeric), ',') as super
FROM village_details_new , aw
WHERE
    "ST_CODE"::integer=3
    AND village_details_new.aw_code::integer = aw.aw_code::integer
group by
    "SUBDIST_CODE",
    state_name,
    "ST_CODE" ,
    dist_name ,
    "DIST_CODE",
    subdist_name
order by "SUBDIST_CODE"
```

i need sum in

```
sum(array_to_string(array_agg(distinct jan_sale::numeric), ',') as super)
```

but its not working please help.........

```
"Punjab";"03";"Gurdaspur";"0301";"Dhar Kalan";"0301001";"10.1620708"
"Punjab";"03";"Gurdaspur";"0301";"Pathankot";"0301002";"8.7883687"
"Punjab";"03";"Gurdaspur";"0301";"Gurdaspur";"0301003";"0"
"Punjab";"03";"Gurdaspur";"0301";"Batala";"0301004";"0"
"Punjab";"03";"Gurdaspur";"0301";"Dera Baba Nanak";"0301005";"5.6477731"
"Punjab";"03";"Kapurthala";"0302";"Bhulath";"0302001";"6.6241262"
"Punjab";"03";"Kapurthala";"0302";"Kapurthala";"0302002";"12.6775959"
"Punjab";"03";"Kapurthala";"0302";"Sultanpur Lodhi";"0302003";"3.1599889"
"Punjab";"03";"Kapurthala";"0302";"Phagwara";"0302004";"3.3310623,8.7898848"
"Punjab";"03";"Jalandhar";"0303";"Shahkot";"0303001";"14.2610899"
"Punjab";"03";"Jalandhar";"0303";"Nakodar";"0303002";"14.2610899"
```

Comment: Wait. What is your actual data? Is it an array? How do you know what `jan_sale` is? What does the source data look like and how is it structured? What is this `aw` table and what is its data? Is ***that*** where the array is?

Comment: How can you "sum" a comma separated list of Strings? And "*not working*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: yaa i need sum of comma separated list of integer how to do that???

Comment: Sum them before putting them into the comma separated list

Comment: how to do that , please specify  i wrote the whole sql ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(distinct jan_sale)::numeric as super
```